# AEM 6.2 upgrade : Custom servlet paths not working after upgrade

Tags: servlets, upgrade, aem

We have custom servlets with registered servlet paths starting with /api/v1/ , /api/v2/. These 
were working fine on 5.6.1. Just after upgrade to 6.2 ( we skipped 6 and 6.1), these servlets started giving 404.

As per docs if we list these paths in felix console configuration Apache sling servlet/script Resolver and Error handler these servlets should be working. I did and still get a 404.

Also if I use the servlet resolver and see what the path evaluates to, it points to the correct servlet's class.

Any idea what extra configuration is required just for 6.2?

Adding recent request logs:

```
Request 47301 (GET /bin/offers/list) by admin - RequestProgressTracker Info
      0 TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/bin/offers/list
      0 TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
      0 TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/bin/offers/list resolves to Resource=ServletResource, servlet=com.xyz.v2.servlets.OffersListServlet, path=/bin/offers/list
      0 LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/bin/offers/list', selectorString='null', extension='null', suffix='null'
      0 TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
      0 TIMER_START{resolveServlet(/bin/offers/list)}
      0 TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(/bin/offers/list)} Using servlet com.xyz.v2.servlets.OffersListServlet
      0 TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/bin/offers/list handled by Servlet=com.xyz.v2.servlets.OffersListServlet
```

/api/v2/user

```
Request 47279 (GET /api/v2/user) by admin - RequestProgressTracker Info
      0 TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/api/v2/user
      0 TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
      0 TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/api/v2/user resolves to Resource=ServletResource, servlet=com.xyz.servlets.UserServlet, path=/api/v2/user
      0 LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/api/v2/user', selectorString='null', extension='json', suffix='null'
      0 TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
      0 TIMER_START{resolveServlet(/api/v2/user)}
      0 TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(/api/v2/user)} Using servlet com.xyz.servlets.UserServlet
      0 TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/api/v2/user handled by Servlet=com.xyz.servlets.UserServlet
      0 LOG Applying Requestfilters
      0 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl
      0 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter
      0 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter
      0 LOG Including resource ApiResourceWrapper, type=granite/rest/core/resource, path=/api/v2/user, resource=[ServletResource, servlet=com.xyz.servlets.UserServlet, path=/api/v2/user] (SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/api/v2/user', selectorString='null', extension='json', suffix='null')
      0 TIMER_START{resolveServlet(/api/v2/user)}
      0 TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(/api/v2/user)} Using servlet com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.DefaultGETServlet
      0 LOG Applying Forwardfilters
```

Comment: Please share stacktrace from logs.

Comment: No logging as such. But I can share the recent request log.

Comment: The error is on publish or when with dispatcher? If publish is processing 404 in that case there will be some exception in logs unless you have modified error handler itself. Point to note is the since servlet resolver is able to resolve your servlet it means servlet as such does work, its the code inside which may be causing issue.

Comment: happens on both author and publish. Debugging the code, didn't even get to the code. so the servlet is never executed.

Comment: As you can see there is a slight difference between first and second recent request logs. /bin is evaluated only once. But /api/v2 is evaluated twice to get the servlet it has to handover the control to.

Comment: why was the question downvoted?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

From initial investigation into you resourceResolution I can say that the `/api` based resources are handled differently in AEM 6.2.

The filter `com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter` checks if the resource path starts with `/api`, this is configured in `ApiEndpointResourceProviderFactoryImpl` you can check in felix configurations - `/system/console/configMgr/com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.ApiEndpointResourceProviderFactoryImpl`

This filter then wraps your request resource to as `granite/rest/core/resource` in `ApiResourceWrapper` which totally changes the resource resolution for your call, which is no longer a call to a path based servlet but a GET call to an existing resource that gets handled by `DefaultGETServlet` which doesn't know what to do with this resource and thus gives out 404.

I am not entirely sure what is the purpose of the /api based specific handling as its not something available in documentation, so i would not suggest changing the felix configurations - `/system/console/configMgr/com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.ApiEndpointResourceProviderFactoryImpl` unless Adobe confirms it. You should reach out DayCare for getting assistance on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Have a daycare ticket in place. Waiting for their input.

Comment: Can you try using /bin instead of /api just for experimentation to see if that works? Also if you feel that the above explanation makes sense, you could add this to your DayCare ticket and then ask for possible solutions.

Comment: changing it to bin works. So issue is with /api alone. Added these details to daycare ticket too.

Answer (score 0):

As of AEM 6.2, the `/api` resource is reserved for the Siren+JSON API used to expose content from the JCR.

Try the following URL for yourself: http://localhost:4502/api/content.json

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "links": [
                {
                    "rel": [
                        "self"
                    ],
                    "href": "http://localhost:4502/api/content/sites/geometrixx-outdoors.json"
                },
                {
                    "rel": [
                        "content"
                    ],
                    "href": "http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx-outdoors.html"
                }
            ],
            "class": [
                "content/page"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "dc:description": "Geometrixx Outdoors - fashion that doesn't sacrifice style for comfort",
                "dc:title": "Geometrixx Outdoors Site",
                "name": "geometrixx-outdoors",
                "redirectTarget": "/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en"
            }
        }
    ],
    "class": [
        "content/page"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "dc:title": "Content Root",
        "name": "content",
        "srn:paging": {
            "total": 13,
            "offset": 0,
            "limit": 20
        }
    }
}
```

More info:
https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren

Comment: @Siva Isukapalli please accept my answer if its correct. Might help other people..